# MySQL - SELECT query - oldest and youngest date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to build one SQL SELECT query. Table structure is as follows:

```
[ID] [PHONE] [description] [DATE]
[1] [600898367] [main] [2016-01-23]
[2] [600898367] [] [2016-01-24]
[3] [600898367] [] [2016-01-26]
[4] [600898367] [] [2016-01-28]
[5] [662349093] [main] [2016-01-10]
[6] [662349093] [] [2016-01-21]
[7] [662349093] [] [2016-01-30]
[8] [662349093] [] [2016-01-31]
```

You have here different records grouped within the same telephone number. The first (the oldest) occurance is marked with [main] flag. There's no two identical numbers with [main] flag. 
I want to select each [main] record and additionaly one youngest with the same phone number, so the result should give records 1,4,5,8.

Please help.

Comment: You can also use UNION for part of this problem

Comment: I have about 100k records in my table. Maybe two separate queries would be faster solution than JOIN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `WHERE` clause to give you the records with the `main` flag. Use `MAX` to get the most recent record and `JOIN` to get the additional columns. Finally, do a `UNION ALL` to combine the result.

```
-- Get the main records first
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE description = 'main'

UNION ALL

-- Get the most recent records
SELECT b.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.PHONE,
        MAX(DATE) AS MaxDate
    FROM tbl t
    GROUP BY PHONE
) a
INNER JOIN tbl b -- Do a JOIN to get the additional columns
    ON b.PHONE = a.PHONE
    AND b.DATE = a.MaxDate
```

Comment: Maybe it's the `MAX(DATE)`:D

Comment: @Reno Nice catch! I need another coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32d1f/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`ID` int, `PHONE` int, `description` varchar(4), `DATE` varchar(11))
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`ID`, `PHONE`, `description`, `DATE`)
VALUES
    (1, 600898367, 'main', '2016-01-23'),
    (2, 600898367, NULL, '2016-01-24'),
    (3, 600898367, NULL, '2016-01-26'),
    (4, 600898367, NULL, '2016-01-28'),
    (5, 662349093, 'main', '2016-01-10'),
    (6, 662349093, NULL, '2016-01-21'),
    (7, 662349093, NULL, '2016-01-30'),
    (8, 662349093, NULL, '2016-01-31')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
inner join (
    select `PHONE`, max(`DATE`) as `DATE` from table1 group by `PHONE`
) t1 on t.`PHONE` = t1.`PHONE` and (t.`DATE` = t1.`DATE` or t.`description` = 'main')
order by t.`ID`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32d1f/1/0)**:

```
| ID |     PHONE | description |       DATE |
|----|-----------|-------------|------------|
|  1 | 600898367 |        main | 2016-01-23 |
|  4 | 600898367 |      (null) | 2016-01-28 |
|  5 | 662349093 |        main | 2016-01-10 |
|  8 | 662349093 |      (null) | 2016-01-31 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.*, t3.*
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT PHONE, MAX(date) AS max_date
   FROM mytable 
   GROUP BY PHONE
) AS t2 ON t1.PHONE = t2.PHONE
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t3 ON t1.PHONE = t3.PHONE AND t2.max_date = t3.`date`
WHERE t1.description = 'main'
```

Comment: I think the op wants a 4 column result

Answer (score 0):

With a `GROUP BY` we'll first group on both `PHONE` and `description`, thus getting 4 rows.

Next we'll create a comma separated set using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). It can take an `ORDER BY` clause, to order the phone numbers by date.

Last we want to get the first item from the set, we can do this with [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`PHONE` ORDER BY `DATE`), ',', 1) AS `PHONE`,
  description
FROM table1
GROUP BY `PHONE`, `description`;
```

---

### [See Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32d1f/6)

Comment: Note: This answer assumes that the `ID` and `DATE` fields aren't required for the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query..

```
SELECT 
  A.* 
FROM
  `old_young` A 
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      MIN(`DATE`) AS Res 
    FROM
      old_young 
    WHERE description = 'main' 
    GROUP BY PHONE 
    UNION
    ALL 
    SELECT 
      MAX(`DATE`) AS Res 
    FROM
      old_young 
    WHERE description = '' 
    GROUP BY PHONE) B 
    ON A.DATE = B.Res ;
```

Check the [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddc90/1)